# Размер изображений на экране (Android Studio)

Tags: android, изображения, android-studio

При добавлении изображения на экран, а именно **ImageView** с параметром **android:src="..."**, изображения принимает "свой размер". Чтобы его изменить на тот, который мне нужен меняю параметры:

```
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
```

так сказать, подгоняю.
Но, проблема в том, что при запуске на устройстве с другим экраном всё собъётся.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, параметр scaleType - это то, что тебе нужно. Попробуй все варианты его.

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="нужные параметры"
    android:layout_height="нужные параметры"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
```

попробуй все варианты.

```
android:scaleType="fit"  
android:scaleType="fitXY"  
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно задать нужные значения в файле `res/values-*/dimens.xml`

вместо * использовать нужные квалификаторы для разных размеров экрана .

`res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml`

```
<resources> 
<dimen name="pic_width">20px</dimen> 
<dimen name="pic_height">30dp</dimen> 
</resources>
```

`res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml`

```
<resources> 
<dimen name="pic_width">40px</dimen> 
<dimen name="pic_height">60dp</dimen> 
</resources>
```

и тд.

Затем использовать так:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="@dimen/pic_width"
android:layout_height="@dimen/pic_height"
/>
```

**UPDATE**
Другой вариант - это использовать изображения разного размера для разных разрешений экрана , чтобы каждое подходило к своему экрану "как есть".
Для этого нужно заготовить изображения нужных размеров , с одним и тем же именем и раскидать их по соотетствующим папкам : `drawable-hdpi/pic.png` `drawable-xhdpi/pic.png` и тд.

затем использовать так:

```
<ImageView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/pic"
 />
```

За первый вариант экономия на размере файла приложения , но качество картинки может сильно страдать при изменении масштаба , соответственно второй вариант решает эту проблему , так как для каждого разрешения экрана - отдельная картинка , которую можно сделать с максимальным качеством , но для всех них нужно место для хранения .