# Размер значков при разных разрешениях экрана

Tags: android

Есть следующая разметка:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton_img1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/img1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="gotoNewActivityimg1"
                    android:alpha="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="///"
                    android:id="@+id/NextViewimg1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton_img2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/img2"
                    android:onClick="gotoNewActivityimg2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:alpha="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="////"
                    android:id="@+id/TextViewimg2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/map"
                    android:onClick="gotoNewActivityMap"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:alpha="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Map_city"
                    android:id="@+id/TextViewMap"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы значки на всех экранах выглядели более-менее "удобнонажимаемыми". Сейчас получается ситуация, что на одном телефоне значки показываются нормального размера (как раз по большой палец), а на другом (с бОльшим разрешением) - слишком мелкие. Как я понимаю, тут необходимо применить параметр layout:weight? Я прав? Если да, то как его грамотно применить?

Comment: Размеры элементов не задаются хардкорно, а подбираются системой , исходя из разрешения экрана - [официальный гайд по этому вопросу](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Размер изображений на экране (Android Studio)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417548/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/
Вот тут можно нарезать иконки под все разрешения

Comment: Android Studio имеет [аналогичный инструмент](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-image-assets.html) - правый клик на изображении в проекте -> New -> Image Asset. Инструмент подготовит под нужные разрешения изображения и они будут автоматически размещены в соответствующих папках.

Comment: Cпасибо большое, даже не знал об этой фишке