# Одинаковый размер иконок внутри приложения

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть `main_layout`, на котором есть 6 иконок (`ImageButton`). Хотелось бы, чтобы все 6 иконок были пропорциональны любому экрану, чтобы не вылезали за пределы экрана и не были слишком большими/маленькими.

Я  задавал уже [подобный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448110/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) вопрос ранее.  Пробовал решение, предложенное [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417548/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5-android-studio) .

В частности, создал несколько каталогов `values-mdpi`, `values-ldpi`, `values-xhdpi`.

В каждом вложенном файле dimens указал разные размеры для иконок.
Как итог: на телефонах mdpi с разным разрешением экрана иконки были разного размера: на телефонах с большим разрешением - маленькие, на телефонах с маленьким разрешением - более-менее нормальные.

Сейчас попробовал создал каталоги `values-w320dp`, `values-w480dp`.
И даже `values-sw320`, `values-sw480dp`. Везде в файле `dimens` указал разные значения.

Как итог: на эмуляторе `Genymotion` телефон 240x320 160 dpi показывал тот же размер иконок, что и на физическом телефоне 1920x1080 hdpi.

Посему опять задаю вопрос:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы иконки выглядели нормально на каждом экране? Именно заданного размера.
2. Какие файлы нужно редактировать? Слышал, что вариант с `values-ldpi` и подобный перечень давно устарел. Какой тогда формат нужно использовать.
   Прошу помочь, так как уже перечитал Android guide не раз и все равно не понял.

Разметка `main_layout`:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout55"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:weightSum="6"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button24"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/wdp2_layout"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/wdp2_layout"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="gotoNewActivityOne"
                    android:alpha="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Car1"
                    android:id="@+id/textView33"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button55"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon2"
                    android:onClick="gotoNewActivityCar2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:alpha="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Car2"
                    android:id="@+id/textView39"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button66"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:background="@drawable/map"
                    android:onClick="gotoNewActivityMap"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:alpha="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Navi"
                    android:id="@+id/textView40"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout51"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:weightSum="6"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:background="@drawable/kalendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="gotoNewActivitycalendar"
                    android:alpha="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="RASP"
                    android:id="@+id/textView41"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:background="@drawable/car3"
                    android:onClick="gotoNewActivityCar3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:alpha="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Car3"
                    android:id="@+id/textView42"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_scrn_pic"
                    android:background="@drawable/car4"
                    android:onClick="gotoNewActivitycar4"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:alpha="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TECH"
                    android:id="@+id/textView43"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Не ориентируйтесь на низкие разрешения. По факту сейчас актуально hdpi и выше. Покажите как вы хотите расположить ваши ImageButton-ы  в разметке

Comment: @АндройдАндройд , вот так я хочу расположить. Вкратце: 2 horizontal LinearLayout, в которые вложены по 3 vertical Linear. И в каждый vertical - по ImageButton и TextView. Есть какие-либо идеи, как сделать задуманное?

Comment: Используйте не просто Button, а ImageButton. У них есть свойство "src" - источник картинки. А так же есть свойство "scale_type", которое скалирует изображение, там есть несколько вариантов. Думаю, что scale_type="fitInside" вам подойдет.

Comment: @Rishka , благодарю, сейчас попробую сделать. А что с текстом в таком случае делать? Указывал размер в sp, а он все равно выглядит одинаково везде: ldpi - просто огромен, hdpi - нормальный , xxxhdpi - мелкий. Как быть?

Comment: fitInside я не вижу в списке. Возможно centerInside подойдет?

Comment: @user186295 поэкспериментируйте сами с scale_type. А насчет текста - не понял. Указывается в sp и что, текст не меняется в размерах? sp как раз и нужен, чтобы текст везде одинаково выглядел. На больших экранах 12sp будет больше, а на маленьких - меньше. То есть, процентальное отношение сохраняется все равно.

Comment: @Rishka , правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно указывать не background , а src? Просто тогда возникает еще один неприятный момент: если в backgroung png иконку показывает отлично, то в src он показывает картинку с белым фоном, а иконка должна быть прозрачной. Возможно, есть какое-то решение этому вопросу?

Comment: @user186295 ну, во-первых, можно попробовать сделать background="@android:color/transparent". Во-вторых, сама иконка в каком формате? Сама иконка должна быть прозрачной.

Comment: Недавно гугл представила новую библиотеку поддержки [support:percent](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/) которая позволяет задать размеры виджетов в процентах от размера контейнера.

Comment: @Rishka , по правде говоря, нужного эффекта я не добился: на больших экранах по-прежнему иконки мелкие, а на маленьких - огромные. Возможно проблема в разметке LinearLayout какая-нибудь?

Comment: @user186295 попробовали все scale_type? Очистите свои папки drawable,drawable-hdpi и прочие от добавленных вами иконок и добавьте по-новому: берете иконку максимального качества, кладете сюда: [генератор иконок](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html)

Comment: @Rishka , а папки-то (именно папки) в res нужно создавать вида drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi и класть туда все иконки, верно?

Comment: @user186295 по-идее, они должны уже присутствовать, когда проект создаете. Но да, так и надо.

Comment: @Rishka , все никак не получается сделать задуманное. Предлагаю по порядку: 1. я заменил Button на ImageButton (добавляя scale_type различного рода). 2. Я заменил background на src (соответственно, @drawable/name. 3. В генераторе иконок сделал иконки hdpi, ldpi, xxhdpi .. 4. Удалил иконку из drawable 5. Добавил все папки, полученные в генераторе. 6. Перезагрузил Android Studio. 7. Все те же иконки, все тот же размер в эмуляторе Genymotion., всё та же проблема. Где-то среди списка я ошибся в действиях?

Comment: @Rishka , хотя, если я пользуюсь функцией "Prewiev all screen sizes" в Android Studio. Все более-менее нормально. Возможно ли, что проблема в эмуляторе?

Comment: @user186295 вполне возможно. Вообще желательно тестировать на реальном устройстве, все же. Это гораздо проще и нагляднее.

Comment: @Rishka , где бы еще найти столько реальных устройств! :) В любом случае, благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 4):

Я предложил бы использовать `android:width = 0dp` и `android.weight = 1` для каждого элемента в горизонтальном `LinearLayout`. Тогда ширина элементов будет пропорционально растягиваться, и при этом занимать всю ширину `LinearLayout`. Для самих изображений можно воспользоваться [Scale Drawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Scale) и задать для него нужный тип масштабирования. И уже этот ресурс указывать в качестве `android:background` или `android:src`.

[Тут есть пример.](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/38-urok-7-layout-parametry-dlja-view-elementov)